# How to find the currently used VB version?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a VB.Net Project and someone suggested me to use the VB2008 IF(a,b,c) operator. I think I am using VB2005, but I can't find where to confirm that information.

Also, is the server's IIS version important for the VB version used? (I think so, but I'd like confirmation... And a way to know what IIS version match what VB version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 separate concerns here

- The version of Visual Studio you are running
- The version of the VB.Net compiler being used

The version of Visual Studio should be very straight forward.  Simply go to the Help menu of Visual Studio and it will identify the version.

Each version of Visual Studio can be used with a specific subset of VB.Net versions.  The default version is the highest version available

- Version 2005: VB.Net 8.0
- Version 2008: VB.Net 9.0 and 8.0
- Version 2010: VB.Net 10.0, 9.0 and 8.0

The `If` operator has been around since VB.Net 9.0 which is generally associated with Visual Studio 2008.

There is no real correlation between IIS versions and VB.Net versions.  IIS is generally configurable to work with whatever version of VB.Net is installed on the machine.  In order to determine that version you'll need to contact the server admin and see what version of the .Net framework IIS is working with.

Comment: If I have the latest IIS version installed, but my application run on .Net framework 1.1, am I limited for my VB.Net version?

Comment: @Kraz yes. For a 1.1 framework you need to use the VB.Net 7.0 or 7.1 compiler which is associated with Visual Studio .Net / 2003.